# Is it possible to create a proper interactive shell over http?

Tags: linux

I want to have a shell access over http to interact with a program running on my server (as opposed to SSH and other protocol).  I have done some research and found two main ways, the php way such as http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpterm/  and the CGI way.  Although these result in shell-like terminals over http, I can't interact with programs with standard input/output without passing paramaters at run: `./prog -options etc..`
With a standard shell over netcat for example `./prog` would provide full interaction so that it could prompt for input etc..

The test program I am running is:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
include<stdlib.h>
int main ()
{

    // set up keyword(passcode)
    char this[14];
    char that[128];

    // check the password and exit if it doesn't match;
    fgets(this, 14, stdin);
    if (strncmp(this, "passwd\n", 14)) {
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("shell interaction success! \n");
    fgets(that, 128, stdin);
    system(that);
    exit(0);
}
```

If run from netcat this would occur:

```
./prog
passwd
Shell interaction success
```

If run from other shell like solutions over http I have come accrss:

```
./prog
then nothing.
```

Fingers crossed someone knows how!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this, but since HTTP is a connectionless request-response protocol, it wouldn't use just *one* HTTP connection.

- A browser would make a request to start a shell on the remote server
- A backend service would be started that creates the desired process and captures the stdin/stdout pipes
- Javascript on the browser would send (POST perhaps) a request to the server to say "this user typed some character"
- Some kind of AJAX request polling loop would get new output from the backend process and display it on the browser

Or, this could be considerably simplified using [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) which is a stream protocol (and is implemented by some browsers but is not HTTP).

Comment: As a note: It is more common to have this done in Java or (God forbid) Flash as WebSockets are much easier to configure and work cross-platform.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: I prefer not to encourage the use of Java or Flash. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. Do you know of any such or near implementation for this at all?  I think its over my experience level.

Comment: @user1088793: I suspect there are implementations of the above, but I don't know of anything specific at the moment.

Comment: Ok, do you think this is a significantly complex coding job? I am considering hiring a freelancer to do it in the case I can't find something.

Comment: Actually I think maybe http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpterm/ is actually doing this other than capturing the stdin/out pipes, maybe I could implement it.

Comment: Yep, it does seem to be doing something like that. It's an interesting starting point, anyway!

Comment: @GregHewgill While I am not a fan of that as a solution, Java and Flash remain the only *truly* cross-browser, cross-platform solutions for this (for the moment).

Comment: @cwallenpoole Javascript is available on a heck of a lot more platforms than this "cross-platform"-claimed Flash thing.

Comment: @jørgensen True, but with over 40% market share belonging to IE < 9, it cannot be assumed that WebSockets will be available yet.

Comment: @cwall there's still AJAX, which has been what has been used so far. With a persistent HTTP connection (HTTP pipelining per HTTP/1.1), it is also reasonably responsive.